Prevent CSV Injection but also need the string starting with special characters which will be used in formula later
In my application, I want to prevent CSV injection for strings starting with attacking characters and I can add single quote at the beginning ' of string that begins with attacking characters.
char[] attackChars = ['=', '@', '+', '-', '\r', '\t'];
if (attackChars.Contains(valueString[0]))
{
      valueString = '\'' + valueString + '\'';
} 

But the problem I am facing is that I still would need some strings that start with special characters. For ex: I have a field named CompanyName which can begin with '+' and this may be used later in a formula -> =IF(LEN(B10)).
I am facing trouble tackling between these issues.
Tackling between security and requirements

This question is similar to: Writing data into CSV file in C#. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
